# How to Count Votes from List and Store in a Dictionary to Track Number of Votes

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Example:

```
list = ["a voted b", "c voted b", "d voted e", "e voted skip", "something else"]
```

Dictionary results:

```
{"b":2, "e":1, "skip":1}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = ["a voted b", "c voted b", "d voted e", "e voted skip"]

votes = defaultdict(int)
for item in mylist:
    votes[item.split()[-1]] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the votes always have the same `x voted y` structure, you could do:

```
# get a defaultdict for storing the result
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)

# split out the voted from each string in the list
pairs = [i.split(' voted ') for i in list]

# for each pair, increase the value for that key in the defaultdict by 1
for _, vote in pairs:
    result[vote] += 1

# convert back to dict
result = dict(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider the list use the following format `x voted y` which x and y changes.
Also, I decided to not use any external library

Here is a function of my code

```py
def count(list):
    # Simplifying the list with the format 'x voted y' to a list with the format 'y'
    votes = [vote.split(' voted ')[1] for vote in list]
    result = {}
    for vote in votes:
        if vote in result.keys():
            result[vote] = result[vote] + 1
        else:
            result[vote] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ["a voted b", "c voted b", "d voted e", "e voted skip"]
v = {}
for i in l:
    vs = i.split(' ')
    if vs[2] not in v:
        v[vs[2]] = 1
        continue
    v[vs[2]] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way might be to use `pandas`:

```
lst = ["a voted b", "c voted b", "d voted e", "e voted skip"]
pd.Series([i.split('voted')[1].strip() for i in lst]).value_counts().to_dict()
```

results in:

```
{'b': 2, 'skip': 1, 'e': 1}
```